# Clarifying trivial destructors

Tags: c++, default, destructor

From IBM.com (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzarg/cplr380.htm)

> A destructor of a class A is trivial if all the following are true:
>
> 1. It is implicitly defined
> 2. All the direct base classes of A have trivial destructors
> 3. The classes of all the nonstatic data members of A have trivial destructors destructor of a class A is trivial (not necessary) if all the following are true:

Interpretations:

1. The constructors that were used within the class were imported. No new constructors were created within the class.
2. From the website: “A direct base class is a base class that appears directly as a base specifier in the declaration of its derived class.” And the rabbit hole continues as I wonder what is a base specifier. Please help.
3. The data types are primitive.

Please comment if any of my interpretations are wrong or can be further simplified for clarity.

```
class Foo {
public:
    ~Foo() { s = “”; x = 0; vi.clear(); }
private:
    string s;
    int x;
    vector<int> vi;
};
```

Given that it is considered a bad practice to create a destructor as shown above, is there an easy way to remember when it is necessary to create a destructor?

Comment: [Write your own destructor if and only if your class explicitly manages a resource](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: A destructor is needed if the member of the class **owns** (is responsible for) resources that are not automatically freed when the class is destructed. (e.g. if the hold owning raw pointers, other resources that are allocated and owned by the class) or if it is a structured like a tree where destruction could lead to a huge amount of recursive destructor calls, that could lead to stack overflows.

Comment: At the moment it’s unclear what part of your question is a verbatim quote from ibm.com. Could you please (1) mark the direct quote as such, using the appropriate markup (`> …`), and (2) include a link referring to the source of the quote?

Comment: Hopefully I corrected the unclear quote and gave the correct corresponding link!

Answer (score 2):

The rule of zero (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)):

> Classes that have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators should deal exclusively with ownership (which follows from the Single Responsibility Principle). Other classes should not have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators.

I like how cppreference is very explicit about it.

Either you write a class that does nothing but manage a resource. In that case you do need to read about the rule of 3/5 (same link). This should be rare, because there are containers and smart pointers that already do mangage resources for you. However a "resource" that should be RAII enabled can be more than just memory, it can be a file, a DB-connection, etc.

Or you write a class the does not manage a resource. In that case you do not need to write a destructor.

Comment: `Or you write a class the does not manage a resource. In that case you do not need to write a destructor.` that is mostly correct. As I wrote in the comment, there is - depending on how you define manage resource - one exception, if the automatic destruction that would be done in a tree like structure result into a huge amount of recursive destruction calls, that could cause a stack overflow, then you should - even if the resource would be deleted automatically - create a destructor that does the releasing of the resources in a better way.

Comment: @t.niese I realized after writing the answer that it just delays the question to "what does it mean to mangage a resource?" and the circle closes by stating that "a class manages a resource when it needs to release it in the destructor". Not sure, but maybe your case can be regarded as "does nothing but manage a resource" because thats basically what a tree does with its nodes. In any case there are always exceptions to a "simple rule"